# delta in global sequencing for SQL Server RML utilities - anyone?

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a hard time trying to get ostress from SQL Server's Microsoft RML Utilities , to work with delta timing for the events. It's a capability that seems to be deprecated (as per the help file) in the last version, the one available on Microsoft download site.

I need it badly, as I have to replay as similar as realtime as possible the trace events ("think time").

The server to be traced is SQL2000 and the server to run the replay workload is SQL2008R2 (it's a db upgrade scenario)

By chance, does anybody already tested this setting on RML Utilities ("Sequencing Options=global sequence,delta" in the .ini file?

Regards,
alvaro

Answer (score 0):

I have used RML Utilities with both the delta setting on and off, it does produce different results. This is with the latest version from Microsoft. So it doesn't look like it's been deprecated.

Using delta still does not replicate the workload in real-time, perhaps this is why it was deprecated.

Did you have any success in the end? I am trying to do something similar myself.